# Kronig Penney model and E-K diagrams

Tags: discussion

Is this the right place to ask for assistance with plotting E-K diagrams for valence and conduction bands and the Kronig Penney model?

Comment: Questions discussing if a question is fit for the stack should go on meta. I flagged the question for migration. Other than that, I think the subject should be on topic.

Comment: @jippie: or maybe physics.stackexchange, since it's a theoretical question, not really about design.